# Dealing with 4 attack as Priest

Tags: hearthstone

I have been playing the Priest hero for some time now, and I try to analyse most of the games played. But one thing that I struggle with in a lot of games, is 4 attack minions on the enemy side of the board.

The Priest has a lot of control cards, such and the Shadow Word cards. But none for handling 4 attack minions. This also counts for the card Shadow Madness.

**How can I as a Priest, effectively handle enemy minions with an attack of 4?**

Comment: I don't understand, what's special about minions with an attack of 4?  What's usually relevant in your ability to deal with them using control cards is their HP

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft What's special is that there's no Shadow Word card that kills minions with 4 attack. Shadow Word Pain kills minions with 3 or less and Shadow Word Kill kills minions with 5 or more.

Comment: I think one of the naxxramas cards for priest will fix this, but I don't remember where I read it and the card is NOT visible in http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Curse_of_Naxxramas

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Aside from your damage spells, remember that you can sometimes buff or debuff the enemy minions from 4 attack to 3 or 5 attack.

For example: If somebody uses a [Chillwind Yeti](http://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/hearthstone.gamepedia.com/e/ea/Chillwind_Yeti%2831%29.png?version=33b629f95f06f8116d6bf7cb21fe0f2f) and you apply your [Dark Iron Dwarf](http://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/hearthstone.gamepedia.com/2/2d/Dark_Iron_Dwarf%28128%29.png?version=0a75c7f3a656da20fd60877a3226da45) effect on his Yeti, it will make his Yeti 6 attack, which will allow you to use [Shadow Word Death](http://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/hearthstone.gamepedia.com/c/ca/Shadow_Word-_Death%28547%29.png?version=c6b08199093591340de1443407fb617e)

Comment: [Shrinkmeister](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Shrinkmeister) from GvG is also a great option.

Answer (score 9):

### How can a Priest deal with 4-attack minions? The same way everyone else does.

Priests are unique in that they have special removal options for creatures of power 3 or less, and power 5 or greater, but that doesn't mean you don't have the same sorts of options others do.

Mainly, direct damage, offensive creatures, and defensive creatures.

Priest have access to excellent direct damage, including Holy Smite, Holy Nova, and Holy Fire. Shadowform is an option too.

You can also use all sorts of creatures for enemy minion removal. Charge minions are great for this, as are minions with high toughness and/or taunt, as you can continually heal and buff them with your hero power, Divine Spirit, and Power Word: Shield.

Comment: I wouldn't answer this exactly the way you did.  "Everyone else" has a hard removal option that eliminates a minion without regard to how much damage it can deal: "Execute", "Hex", "Polymorph" etc. But I see your point.

Comment: I cant say that I agree 100%. Holy Smite is not a direct counter to a minion with 4 attack. Holy Smite is a deal 2 damage card. Holy Nova is a deal 2 damage card and heal 2. I'm sorry, but I cant see how these deal with a 4 attack minion unless its a 2 Health minion. Holy Fire is a better counter yes, but expensive for 1 minion removal. Like BlackVegetable says, the other Heroes has more low cost minion removal options.

Comment: Except Druid. You should never want to use Naturalize unless you're going to win that turn. (Or your opponent is at a full hand, I suppose) Beyond that, Don't forget that Priest has *the most* hard removal -- 2x Shadow Word Pain, Death, and Mindcontrol. The sweet spot of 4 attack is because they have so much otherwise.